# naming methods with different return types but the same functionality

Tags: java

I'm talking about Java, but the concept would apply to other languages --

We have two methods on the same class that will have the same basic functionality, but provide different return types. Both methods will get you all the things, but one gets an iterable which can provide access to all things, and one gets a collection which includes all things.

We know you cannot do this (because it won't compile):

```
Iterable getThings()

Collection getThings()
```

So, does anyone have thoughts about how to name the methods? It seems an easy fix to say:

```
Iterable getIterableOfThings

Collection getCollectionOfThings
```

However, this is obviously somewhat verbose and perhaps not the best solution. Does the question I'm asking imply that our organization/coding approach is somehow off the mark, or is this a valid question?

Has anyone else dealt with this scenario?

Comment: what about `Iterable iterator()` instead of `Iterable getThings()`

Comment: [`Iterable` is a superinterface of `Collection`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) Why do you need two getters when you can always cast one to the other?

Comment: Verbosity should not be feared, since we have IDE's that can save a lot of typing for us.  You might want to check out [Bob Martin's _Clean Code..._](http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1403192998&sr=8-1&keywords=bob+martin+clean+code).  Having said that, I still don't know how to name things.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Iterable getIterator();
Collection getThings();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Iterable is a superinterface of Collection.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) Generally speaking you *shouldn't* need to do this.

Nonetheless, the question itself is valid. A better example is when you have, say, an underlying resource, and one function wrapping it in one access object and the second in another. It depends on coding style, of course, but I for one am used to seeing something like this (and thus find it more readable):

```
class A {
    private Object[] underlying;
    List<Object> getItemsAsList() {
        return Arrays.asList(underlying);
    }
    Object[] getItemsAsArray() {
        return underlying;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterable getThings() does not seem correct as you are not actually getting anything. Iterable provides access to iterate over a set of items but does not give you those items.

A collection will give you those items, so Collection getThings() seems right.

For example you can be given an iterator for an infinitely long set but no such equivalent collection could be given. This would work because the iterator would return an element at time but a collection would need to collect the infinite amount of objects and return them.

Comment: What's wrong with, say, `Iterable getItems(){return new ArrayList();}`?

Comment: @blgt - There is nothing wrong with that but ArrayList implements Collection not just Iterable. This is a matter of a dog is a 4 legged animal but not all 4 legged animals are dogs.